# How to output buffer every 10% of the total number?

Tags: php

I want to print a dot every 10% of the total number. But its only printing one dot. Here’s my code:

```
$numRows = 123;
$count = 0;

while(true){
    $count++;
   
    if($count == round((($numRows*10)/100))){
    echo “.”;
    echo str_repeat(‘ ‘, 1024*64);
    }
    }
```

Sorry about the format, I’m on mobile. Is there anything I’m missing here? Don’t worry about the while loop, i just simplify the code.

Comment: `$count` goes up by one in each loop iteration, but the result of `round((($numRows*10)/100))` never changes. So how did you expect this to do something more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use output buffering you could use the built-in functions https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php there you can provide a chunk size that will flush the buffer when reached.

When you need this every 10% behavior instead of buffering you have to change your code cause currently you only calculate 10% of 123 once but for every 10% you would have to add your calculated value for the next 10%.

Currently you compare only with 12 but you should have the logic like:
Reached 12 (first 10%) then the next limit should be 24 etc…